# using INSERT for an xml statement

Tags: t-sql

how would you go about inserting an xml document of information into an existing table, I cannot figure out how the insert statement would work my code is below:

```
USE MyGuitarShop;

DECLARE @CustomerUpdate XML;
SET @CustomerUpdate = '
    <NewCustomers>
    <Customer LastName="Chan" FirstName="Isabella" Password="" EmailAddress="izzychan@yahoo.com"/>
    <Customer LastName="Prine" FirstName="John" Password="" EmailAddress="johnprine@gmail.com"/>
    <Customer LastName="Kitchen" FirstName="Kathy" Password="" EmailAddress="kathykitchen@sbcglobal.net"/>
    </NewCustomers>
    '
;

INSERT INTO Customers (LastName, Password, EmailAddress)
VALUES (@CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
(@CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
(@CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/Password)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
(@CustomerUpdate.value('(/NewCustomers/EmailAddress)[1]', 'varchar(50)');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're selecting the **node** `LastName` from `NewCustomers`, while `NewCustomers` contains only `Customer` nodes, which then contain `LastName` attribute.

In order to select the last name, use the following query instead:

```
value('(/NewCustomers/Customer/@LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

Since you're extracting the data from a single XML value, the selection is pretty straightforward:

```
declare @CustomerUpdate xml;
set @CustomerUpdate = '
<NewCustomers>
    <Customer LastName="Chan" FirstName="Isabella" Password="" EmailAddress="izzychan@yahoo.com"/>
    <Customer LastName="Prine" FirstName="John" Password="" EmailAddress="johnprine@gmail.com"/>
    <Customer LastName="Kitchen" FirstName="Kathy" Password="" EmailAddress="kathykitchen@sbcglobal.net"/>
</NewCustomers>';

select
    t.Customer.value('@LastName', 'nvarchar(50)') as [LastName],
    t.Customer.value('@FirstName', 'nvarchar(50)') as [FirstName],
    t.Customer.value('@Password', 'nvarchar(50)') as [Password],
    t.Customer.value('@EmailAddress', 'nvarchar(50)') as [EmailAddress]
from @CustomerUpdate.nodes('(/NewCustomers/Customer)') t(Customer)
```

If you were selecting the data from a row of XML values, you would have used `cross apply` instead.

---

Important note: **DON'T STORE PASSWORDS IN PLAIN TEXT IN A DATABASE**. If you're actually doing it, you do it wrong. If you don't understand why, learn about hash and salt, or, better, let others handle personal information for you: OpenID is one of the ways of moving the responsibility of securing sensitive data from you to Google-scale companies.